# In theory can Samsung devices get root without tripping Knox, for example by exploit?

Tags: samsung, rooting, samsung-knox

According to [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Knox)

> Before booting in the main Kernel, Samsung runs a "pre-boot"
> environment where it checks for the signature match of all elements of
> the OS.

If a method to get root that does not rely on the bootloader existed, would this bypass Knox? For example if an exploit was found? After the e-fuse for Knox is tripped, can it be untripped, or no because it's physical?

Comment: No, you can think of Knox as being a part of [TEE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_execution_environment), so bypassing that is theoretically possible but practically impossible (if you could tinker with TEE you'd be a rock star of that world) // Knox isn't physical, it's an *electronic fuse*. Once it's blown, you need to replace the chip, which is beyond a user

Comment: @JonDon I think your question is misformulated, therefore beeshyams answer is no. "Knox" is not only the bootloader check, Knox is the name of the whole security system of Samsung devices. I think your real question is "will the device be able to detect if I do something with temporary root permissions gained by an exploit".

Comment: not possible https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/bounty-sm-n975u1-note-10-usa-unlocked-version-bootloader-unlock-and-root-method.4006249/page-12#post-82510563